# How to prevent splitted views from scrolling together when editing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open one file in two split views in visual studio CODE, I can scroll them separately to a different position. I can edit in one view and see another position in the other view. However, when I hit return to add a new line, the other view suddenly jumps to that position, which is rather annoying.

Not sure, whether this is a bug or a feature. How can it be disabled?

Comment: What type of file are you editing?  I'm seeing the same behavior, but only when editing *.py files

Comment: I see it with *.ts (TypeScript) files